# How can I pass an integer N and returns an integer array with N elements?

Tags: java

How can I create a method that is passed an integer N and returns an integer array with N elements? The elements should contain the numbers from 1 to N in reverse order, the first element will contain N, the second will contain N-1, etc. Also the return value of this method should be an integer array. Thanks in advanced!

Comment: If you have your attempt so far, please post it, and then people will be happy to offer guidance.  But, StackOverflow doesn't do your work for you.

Comment: do you want to reverse order array of passed elements?

Comment: yes i want to reverse @avi

Answer (score 2):

Declare something as `new int[N]`, fill it, and return it.

Answer (score 0):

With Java 8 you could do something like:

```
return IntStream.iterate(N, i -> i - 1).limit(N).toArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [collection.reverse()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#reverse%28java.util.List%29)
put your numbers in a `List` of `Integers`
use this :

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1, 4, 9, 16, 9, 7, 4, 9, 11);
System.out.println(list);
Collections.reverse(list);
System.out.println(list);
```

you will have this :

```
[10, 14, 91, 16, 9, 7, 4, 9, 11]
[11, 9, 4, 7, 9, 16, 91, 14, 10]
```

Comment: is there anyway to do it without using arraylist?

Comment: sorry for inconvenience but, i am C# developer that's what i know about the java. :(